# Keeping a countOf<Key> attribute on a NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

There are many questions related to sorting by the count of a relationship (using `NSFetchRequest` and/or `NSFetchedResultsController`) on a `NSManagedObject`, but I haven't found any examples of best practice for keeping a persisted `countOf<Key>` updated.

So, what are some of the best ways to update a persisted `countOf<Key>` attribute immediately after the `<key>` attribute changes?

Comment: This answered question seems relevant, but lacks illustrating code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618902/core-data-keypathsforvaluesaffectingvalueforkey-only-calling-relationships-not

Comment: Key-Value Observing Programming Guide -> Registering Dependent Keys -> To-many Relationships seems very relevant, but I can't quite crack the generic, vague formulation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-SW5