# CoreData attribute value based on other attributes

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a number of attributes for a CorData entity that are based on the values of other attributes. For example transactionTotalValue = transactionPrice * transactionQuantity.  Currently I subclassed the NSManagedObject and created custom setters like this

```
- (void)setTransactionQuantity:(NSDecimalNumber *)transactionQuantity
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"transactionQuantity"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:transactionQuantity forKey:@"transactionQuantity"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"transactionQuantity"];
    [self updateTotalValue];
}

- (void)setTransactionPrice:(NSDecimalNumber *)transactionPrice
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"transactionPrice"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:transactionPrice forKey:@"transactionPrice"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"transactionPrice"];
    [self updateTotalValue];
}

- (void)updateTotalValue
{
    self.transactionTotalValue = [self.transactionQuantity decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[self.transactionPrice decimalValue]]];
}
```

Is this an acceptable way of doing this? if not what would be considered best practice for this situation?

The other alternative is to use KVO as follows

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)transactionTotalValue
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"transactionTotalValue"];
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [self.transactionQuantity decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[self.transactionPrice decimalValue]]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"transactionTotalValue"];
    return total;
}


+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSSet *keypaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"transactionTotalValue"]) {
        NSArray *affectingKeys = @[@"transactionQuantity", @"transactionPrice"];
        keypaths = [keypaths setByAddingObjectsFromArray:affectingKeys];
    }
    return keypaths;
}
```

Is this the better option?

Comment: Just curious - is there a reason you're using KVO?

Comment: @LyricalPanda I assume you mean "Not" using KVO.   And the answer is no, there is no reason, I'm trying to determine what is the best accepted practice for this case.  I updated my question to include KVO.  Is this the best solution?

Comment: No, when you were using self willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey that was using KVO (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Honestly unless you are really doing anything with KVO, you can drop your setTransactionQuantity/Price methods and let the synthesized properties take care of it. When doing this kind of thing the only method I had was `- (int) getTotalValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `transactionTotalValue` is to be completely dependent upon the two other attributes.
Declare it as a readonly, nonatomic property.

`@property (nonatomic,readonly) id transactionTotalValue;`

You can then implement the getter.

```
- (id)transactionTotalValue 
    {
        //check for non-existent needed properties and handle here

        return [self.transactionQuantity 
        decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber 
        decimalNumberWithDecimal:[self.transactionPrice decimalValue]]];
    }
```

Also override the class method for keys that affect the dependent property.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTransactionTotalValue
    {
        return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"transactionQuantity", @"transactionPrice", nil];
    }
```

The `transactionTotalValue` property will be re-read as needed, say if you are updating a table source through bindings. By making it readonly you will be able to avoid any setter methods.

Comment: So you wouldn't make transactionTotalValue an attribute of the CoreData Entity

Comment: Yes, it will be an attribute, as a readonly property that you set up in the NSManagedObject subclass for that entity. You won't have to do the setters because those other attributes, the ones it is dependent upon, are what the user sets. The user will never set the dependent property directly.

Comment: To clarify a bit more, there is no need for custom setters for transactionPrice and transactionQuantity.

Comment: Thanks Mike, one more question, Why aren't the willAccess and didAccess change notifications necessary

Comment: When the attribute is completely dependent, you can set it up as readonly without setters or an ivar to be managed. As a property it will still be part of KVO by way of its custom getter and the `+ keyPathsForValuesAffecting<key>` class method.

Comment: I think this solution is not correct. First of all the transactionTotalValue will become a simple derived property, and it will not be stored in Core Data. That means no way to use it in NSExpression, fetch predicates, subquery, groupby etc. Moreover,  +KeyPathsForValuesAffecting<key> will not be called without an observer. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618902/core-data-keypathsforvaluesaffectingvalueforkey-only-calling-relationships-not